# Error : undefined symbol getSupportFragmentManager() in a fragment

Tags: android

Here i am using android fragment my java file is extends Fragment but i am getting error at getSupport fragmentManager i.e undefined symbol

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video, container, false);

    try {
        context = getActivity();
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        txtTotalVideo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_total_video);

        adapter = new Youtube_VideoRecyclerAdapter(context);

        youtubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) this.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.frame_fragment);
```

Comment: use this way youtubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.frame_fragment);

Answer (score 0):

**please use getActivity instead of this**

youtubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) **getActivity()**.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.frame_fragment);